# Read logs from the remote server

Tags: linux, gui, logs, remote-access

I have a Spring Boot server which generates Logback logs. Now I need to read these logs on the remote server from the local machine(e.g. my PC). But the main problem is that I will not have a constantly turned on computer that will constantly receive logs. So, I want to produce logs on the remote server, and when I need to check the logs I want to connect to this server and read them on my local machine. I am looking for a simple solution for reading logs five to ten times a day.

I already looked on the ELK stack, this would be a great solution, but unfortunately `ELK` consumes some resources so I can't install entire ELK stack on the remote server. Another option is to use Filebeat on the remote server side, but it is also not suitable because I will not have a constantly turned on computer that will constantly receive logs.

So, please advise lightweight and simple software which meets my requirements for reading logs.

Comment: Is it just log files – so copying them to your local machine would be acceptable? Or does it need specific software to read those logs via some API? Are command-line solutions acceptable, or is a GUI required? And just in case it comes to paid solutions, what is the price limit?

Comment: @Izzy just copying to local machine - exhausting and can lead to human errors. I prefer a GUI like Kibana. And now I have found cloud based solutions like Logsene and Loggly. What do you think about them?

Comment: No idea, I'm not using any such (btw I would never use cloud-based stuff, trusting "other people's computers" with my data, especially when it comes to things which might contain sensitive stuff). And by copying I didn't necessarily mean doing that manually. Just trying to fill the gaps here so someone into the area can give a good recommendation.